# How can I increment the number on the end of my variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below this text is a few lines of code that set up my check box, however I don't want to write this out 5 times.

The checkbox is a button that changes it's title label when I click it. I have achieved this by reusing a functions.

However I am still curious as to whether it is possible to use a for loop to increment a number on the end of a variable name?

```
 [[checkbox layer]setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor]];
 [[checkbox layer]setBorderWidth:0.1];
 [[checkbox layer]setCornerRadius:5];
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
 [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(check)];
 [checkbox addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Comment: still not clear enough what you want.
If you want the same checkbox then why bother writing the same code for 5 times?

Comment: is checkbox a button?

Comment: Rather than using individual IBOutlets you can use an IBOutletCollection which is an array and you can loop through it and call a method such as the one in saheb's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a separate method like this

```
-(void)setupWithCheckBox:(UIButton *)button{ 
//this is assuming checkbox is a button 
  [[button layer]setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor]];
 [[button layer]setBorderWidth:0.1];
 [[button layer]setCornerRadius:5];
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
 [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(check)];
 [button addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}
```

Then call the method 5 times with different buttons you want.Suppose you have 5 buttons inside a `UIView` called `myView`. Then call the above method like this

```
for(UIButton *btn in myView){
if([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
[self setupWithCheckBox:btn];
}
```

This is all assuming that checkbox is a button, If its not then substitude `UIButton` in the snippet with whatever class it is. But i think its a button.

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm doing at the moment I was just wondering if you could actually do that by incrementing the number :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 20, 20)];
button.tag=9;
button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:button];

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){

   UIButton *lastBtn=(UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:9+i];

        CGRect frame=lastImg.frame;
        frame.origin.x+=frame.size.width+8;

        UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

        btn.tag=9+i+1;
        [self.view addSubview:btn];

        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;


        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"btn":btn,@"lastBtn":lastBtn};


        [_view_back addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[lastBtn]-8-[btn]"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:viewsDictionary]];

        NSLayoutConstraint *width =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                    constraintWithItem:btn
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                    relatedBy:0
                                    toItem:lastImg
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                    multiplier:1.0
                                    constant:0];
        NSLayoutConstraint *height =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                     constraintWithItem:btn
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                     relatedBy:0
                                     toItem:lastBtn
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                     multiplier:1.0
                                     constant:0];

        NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:btn
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:lastBtn
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                   constant:0.f];

        [_view_back addConstraint:width];
        [_view_back addConstraint:height];
        [_view_back addConstraint:top];

    }
```